# JS. выдает предупреждение closure-compiler на document.onmousemove = null;

Tags: javascript, closure-compiler

Здравствуйте, почему closure-compiler бросает предупреждения (warning) если я отменяю события с помощью document.onmousemove = null; Значит я что-то делаю не по этикету?

Вопрос: как правильно обнулять document.onmousemove ?
Вывод closure-compiler:

```js
JSC_TYPE_MISMATCH: assignment
found   : null
required: function (?): undefined at line 201 character 8
        document.onmousemove = null; // чистим
        ^
JSC_TYPE_MISMATCH: assignment
found   : null
required: function (): undefined at line 202 character 8
        document.onmouseup   = null; // чистим
        ^
JSC_TYPE_MISMATCH: assignment
found   : null
required: function (?): undefined at line 293 character 8
        document.onmousemove = null; // чистим
        ^
JSC_TYPE_MISMATCH: assignment
found   : null
required: function (?): undefined at line 294 character 8
        document.onmouseup   = null; // чистим
        ^
```

Comment: написано же в самой ошибке `required: function (): undefined`, попробуйте приравнивать к `undefined`,а не к `null`

Comment: а навешивались события таким же присваиванием?

Comment: @Grundy, да, таким-же